# CMD - Ignoring spaces inside Quotes

Tags: windows, cmd, code-coverage, coverlet

I know this is a very trivial question. I have tried and failed.

Though it's not relevant to the question, what I'm trying to do is to get code coverage for an application using coverlet.console like this:

```
coverlet someapp.dll --targetargs "vstest someapp.dll --logger:trx;LogFileName=someapp.trx"
```

The targetargs is invoked from inside coverlet. 
Here, **vstest** is an environment variable in the host system. But, I cant and dont want to set that env variable, so I tried invoking using the path to the exe directly like this:

```
vstest = "C:\Program Files (x86)\[...path]\vstest.console.exe"
coverlet someapp.dll --targetargs "%vstest% someapp.dll --logger:trx;LogFileName=someapp.trx"
```

Now, I'm not able to get to that exe using this variable as the spaces in the path are not ignored.

What can I do here to get to that exe file inside the argument string?

**Update:**

As per the comments, doing this I was able to achieve the desired result.

```
set vstest = "C:\Program Files (x86)\[...path]\vstest.console.exe"
coverlet someapp.dll --targetargs "vstest someapp.dll --logger:trx;LogFileName=someapp.trx"
```

Comment: That doesn't look like `cmd` syntax. Maybe PowerShell? When you define a variable `$vstest`, you should use it with `$vstest`, not `vstest`. (Variables in `cmd` are used like `%variable%`)

Comment: Thanks. Missed these changes while composing the question. It is CMD syntac indeed. Edited it. I hope the question is clear now.

Comment: In CMD, double quotes disable evaluation of special characters such as `&`, except for `%`, and ignore spaces in the executable path of an external command. But double quotes are still passed literally in the command line, and the command line is what gets passed to `CreateProcessW`. Parsing the command line is entirely up to the child process, such as "coverlet". This is different from a shell in Unix, which parses a command line into an array, as required by the Unix `exec` system call.

Comment: You need the `set` command to set a variable in `cmd`. See `set /?`

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Using `set` solved the issue. Removed % from the variable inside args too.

Comment: you didn't set a variable `vstest`, but a variable `vstest<space>`. Remove any spaces around the `=` with the `set` command. When you don't use `%`s around the  variable names, you don't use a variable, but the literal string `vstest`. Your updated code just can't do what you claim.